# Add a dependent framework while creating a custom dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, frameworks

I am creating a framework A on top of framework B. Framework A will have few calls from framework B. So how can I embed framework B in framework A?
I add the framework B in framework A and export the framework A. Now I use framework A in some other project I get an error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Highcharts.framework/Highcharts
>     Referenced from: /Users/chetan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/63A9768B-2130-4D3C-899A-B41E8AAEF600/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C961A4F-F89B-412C-89A6-2EB7BD236B24/TestingLib.app/TestingLib
>     Reason: image not found

So the framework B is `Highcharts` library.